# Python + Browser with Mac: Error - 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, macos, browser, splinter

I did the following but came across the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('chrome')
```

How can I go about resolving the issue using Mac?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer!

Comment: read this: http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drivers/chrome.html?highlight=driver

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The easiest way to resolve this is on a Mac is to:

```bash
brew install --cask chromedriver
```

Splinter and similar frameworks for browser automation rely on external modules being installed and callable in PATH.

Edit: chromedriver migrated from homebrew/core to homebrew/cask

Comment: omg people have no idea this thing exist, I read forums with 100s of comments.

Comment: seriously, if I could vote up your answer a million times, I would

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried all possibilities and they didn't work out but this did!

Comment: So you're saying 'homebrew' does a "proper" install of modules than say PIP? It actually updates the PATH, etc? Wow.

Comment: brew cask install chromedriver

Comment: This solution only worked for me when I entered the following command: brew install --cask chromedriver. So "cask" must be an option with "--". Thank you for the solution :-).

Comment: Please update to the new syntax: brew install --cask chromedriver

Answer (score 10):

`brew cask install chromedriver`

The current working command to install chromedriver from brew, since the previously accepted answer has been outdated unfortunately.

This then needs to be paired with your selinium code :

```
chrome_path = r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver' #path from 'which chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)

or 

import os 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.popen('which chromedriver').read().strip())
```

Note: you may also need to do :
`brew cask install google-chrome`

or

`brew install --cask chromedriver`

depending on your version of brew.

Comment: Please update to the new syntax:
brew install --cask chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three steps and you are all set !!!

1. Change the permission of the exe file to read/write for the user you are using to execute the file.
2. Check the version of the driver is same as that of your browser
3. Also don't give .exe in the python path(just provide upto the `chromedriver` in the path)

example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver")
```